# Write a static void method - "cannot find symbol" compile error

Tags: java, static, program-entry-point, void

This is my assignment:

Write a static void method called greeting with three String parameters that formats and prints a title, first name, and last name in the following format and prints it out.

```
blank line
Dear title first name last name, 
blank line
```

So far, I wrote this code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GreetingLab {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException    {
    String title;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    Scanner in;
    in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a title:");
    title = in.next();
    System.out.print("Enter your first name:");
    firstName = in.next();
    System.out.print("Enter a your last name:");
    lastName = in.next();
    greeting(title,firstName,lastName);
  }
private static void greeting (String ttl, String fName, String lName)
  {
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println ("Dear "+ttl+" "+fName+" "+lname+",");
  System.out.println();
  }
}
```

but it keeps giving me this error:

```
1 error found:
File: /Users/chanelkinard/Desktop/GreetingLab.java [line: 21]
Error: /Users/chanelkinard/Desktop/GreetingLab.java:21: cannot find symbol
symbol : variable lname
location: class GreetingLab
```

This is line 21 from the above code:

```
System.out.println ("Dear "+ttl+" "+fName+" "+lname+",");
```

Comment: On static method; see the **`lName`** and **`lname`**. change it accordingly

Answer (score 5):

Java is case sensitive - change the `println` argument to match the method argument

```
System.out.println("Dear " + ttl + " " + fName + " " + lName + ",");
                                                        ^
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing from `lname` to `lName`

Comment: no look closer to method arguments

Comment: @andand Actually, it is an (and, apparently, _the_ answer).  It's just a very short one.

Answer (score 0):

Your parametername is : "lName" not lname. :)

Answer (score 0):

your method signature has lName, but you access it as lname with a lower n.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled "`lName`" instead you used "`lname`"  (letter n not capitalized)